# Plot lines of varying colors in Matlab R2014b

Tags: plot, colors, mapping, rgb, matlab-figure

I would like to plot lines with colors representing the intensity of some measurment in the form of a vector. With scatter you can plot points with the color given by a color vector but in plot I would have to give an RGB vector. I would like to know how can I map my vector to an RGB vector? Or is there some other method?

Thanks a lot, and tell me if I didn't give some information

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the number of lines you have to plot, one solution would be to use the built-in colormaps. Crude example:

```
intensityVector = [0.1 0.5 1]; % some intensities

% Data you want to plot
x=1:0.1:16;
data1 = zeros(1,length(x));
data2 = sin(x);
data3 = cos(x);

% Let's get an appropriate colormap
cm = colormap(hot);
close; % because colormap call opens a figure

% In order for the line to be differentiable, let's add an offset
offset=10;

figure()
hold on
plot(data1,'Color',cm(1*offset,:),'LineWidth',3);
plot(data2,'Color',cm(2*offset,:),'LineWidth',3);
plot(data3,'Color',cm(3*offset,:),'LineWidth',3);

legend({'data1','data2','data3'});
```